# How to make GWT Spring project as maven enabled

Tags: gwt, spring-mvc, gwt-2.4, gwt-maven-plugin

I have a project which we implemented using GWT and Spring.
I want to make the project as maven enabled.

How can i achieve that? 
I have seen GWT maven plugin. Is it definately required?

Thanks,
Saritha.

---

in the following link, I am unable to find how to add the plugin in the eclipse.
 **http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/**

how to run the  **mvn archetype:generate**

I have followed **http://www.uptick.com.au/content/getting-started-gwt-maven-and-eclipse** link to install the gwt maven plugin. Everything was successful after that when iam trying to create maven project iam unable to find **gwt-maven-plugin archetype**

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can probably write you own.. but in the meantime have a look at http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/. I think the [archetype](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html) is really usefull, because default GWT project does not necessarily follow Maven directory convention.